# Using guava retry framework to keep retrying at fixed interval of time

Tags: java, guava

I am using Guava retry in one of my project. I want to keep retrying at fixed interval if my method doesn't return true. As soon as it returns true, it should get stopped.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Callable<Boolean> callable = new Callable<Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello: " + new Date());
        boolean status = false;
        return status;
      }
    };

    Retryer<Boolean> retryer =
        RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder().retryIfResult(Predicates.<Boolean>alwaysTrue())
            .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.fixedWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
            .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.neverStop()).build();
    try {
      boolean abc = retryer.call(callable);
      System.out.println("world" + abc);
    } catch (RetryException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I have got the above code and it keeps retrying every one minute. Now if at runtime, I change the value of status to `true`, then it should get stopped but it didn't got stopped. Any idea what's wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong predicate. Your predicate always return 'true' and ignoring test your result from retry. Provide proper predicate:

```
Predicate<Boolean> predicate = new Predicate<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Boolean input) {
            return !input;
        }
    };
RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder().retryIfResult(predicate)
```

Comment: hmm I got confuse so how  does my code will look like with this change?

Comment: I edited my answer please check.  According to retryIfResult method docs, it will retry every time if predicate returns true.

Comment: I want to retry if it always returns false and once it returns true, then it should get stopped. How would I do that?

Comment: Please check predicate, I edited condition to fit your requirement.

Comment: Also I can't uderstand how you are going to change status variable if it is in private ownership of Callable:call(). If you want get access to this variable, you should move it outside callable.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify here:

```
RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder().retryIfResult(Predicates.<Boolean>.equalTo(true))
```

and then when the result changes to false, the retry will stop.

Comment: Thankyou for your edit，I'm a new hand and I will pay attention to the format later.